# Continuity of theta correspondence

Tags: rt.representation-theory

If theta correspondence established a map from unitary dual of G to unitary dual of H,then is the map continous w.r.t Fell topology of both unitary duals?

Comment: What's G and H?

Comment: @Bullet51 They are dual groups. See http://www.math.toronto.edu/skudla/castle.pdf

Comment: The question remains what is your setting: real groups, $p$-adic groups, groups over a non-archimedean local field? There is even a form of theta correspondence over finite fields. (Fell topology is defined for any locally compact group.)